# Is accessing Cockpit through SSH tunnel secure?

Tags: ssh, tunneling

I can't find a definite answer on accessing [cockpit](https://cockpit-project.org/) from outside machines securely. Just allowing it through the firewall like that doesn't seem safe. It only uses basic user and password authentication. I think cockpit uses fail2ban to protect against brute forcing password, but is that enough?

So I thought that SSHing into the machine over Internet and then forwarding 9090 port should work - it works for VNC after all. Or is it... is there any vulnerability I might be missing here? Is there perhaps a better way of accessing Cockpit remotely?

I'm running it on a home Ubuntu box.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're jumping through hoops that you don't need. Whether cockpit uses fail2ban or not is a good question, but as for whether you should put cockpit's port 9090 directly on the internet, or wrap it in an ssh tunnel ... why? Cockpit registers itself as a system pam module ([see cockpit docs](https://cockpit-project.org/guide/latest/authentication.html#initial-auth)) which means that when you interact with the cockpit login page, you're actually interacting with the core system login mechanism the same way you would if you were interacting with the ssh server.

I only gave cockpit a quick look a couple of years ago, but it seemed solid to me. I would feel comfortable exposing cockpit's port 9090 directly. *(unless I'm also missing something)*

Comment: Does it mean that we should use PAM somehow to protect from obvious password brute force attack? Like setting up 2 factor authentication in PAM? I haven't found anything hinting at this...

Comment: You're talking about putting the SSH port on the internet and then proxying Cockpit over SSH. I'm just pointing out that you're logging into the same user with the same password regardless of whether you're doing it over SSH or Cockpit. If you have an obvious password then exposing the SSH port instead is not going to protect you. (Now, whether Cockpit supports ssh keys might be worth exploring)

Comment: exactly, I am baffled that Cockpit doesn't seem to have ssh key support - yes, using SSH with password defeats the purpose completely, I meant using SSH with a public key

Comment: Yeah that is surprising. How would that work? Cockpit is browser-based and I didn't think that browsers could do SSH (though that would be a super neat feature to be able to SSH-auth to a website!)

Comment: hmm that is a good point... but I am still not sure how this isn't super vulnerable to brute forcing (without setting up something like kerberos)? Should it be reinforced with something like google-authenticator-libpam?

Answer (score 0):

[SSH Forwarding or Wireguard VPN it is.](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxadmin/comments/g9wm0e/question_about_cockpit_on_a_public_facing_server/) Not-exposing-critical-infrastructure-over-the-Internet-and-using-a-reverse-proxy part was lost on me

Answer (score 0):

There's not much inherent difference between accessing the service via an ssh tunnel or over TLS or over a VPN once the connection is established - but TLS is built into browsers and webservers/most proxies while the ssh and VPN are not. And with mutual TLS authentication you can also add public key validation of both ends of the connection.

Is fail2ban sufficient to prevent brute-force attacks? It's certainly very effective, and has value for limiting/mitigating other types of attack if appropriately configured. But its only one layer of your security onion.